# AVCam causing errors in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6, avcam

Can anyone direct me to a iOS6 tutorial on AVCam like this one:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112

(it wont work for iOS6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpful?

[How to Play, Record, and Edit Videos in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

If there are iOS 6 issues with the code there, ask in the forums and it can be updated.